# send an object that contains variables to a function

Tags: javascript, function, object

What I'm trying to is this. I have a function `chart (params){ }` in a javascript file. Params are not just a variable but an object containing other variables. I want to store variables in this object (*params*) from an html file and then call the function.

I think the code will look something like this, although I haven't managed to make it work.

```
var params = new object();

params.type = 'bar';

...

carts (params);
```

Comment: That's because it should be `new Object()` _notice the capital B_. Although, creating objects is more commonly done in the way UncleDave has answered

Comment: Remember that there is, besides the typo, nothing wrong with this method. Indeed it is antiquated, but not less valid. I even think many new coders don't even know the mechanics behind shorthands like  `[]` and `{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
var params = { type: 'bar' };

chart(params);
```

Note how the object can have initial values set, you can also add additional **properties** to this object in the same way you're already trying to:

`params.somethingElse = 'potato'`

Comment: and I can repeat this for a lot of variables? say var params = { type: 'bar', title = 'stackoverflow', ...};?

Comment: You can add whatever you want to the object as long as each property has a unique key. e.g. you can't add "type" twice without overriding the initial value. Your example is exactly correct.

Answer (score 0):

If params is an object you can always call your function like this

```
chart({type: 'bar', x: 10, y: 20})
```

You can also call this in the same way from html as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this fiddle that I have made. You can add as many parameters as you want and store it in the object.

```
var params = {
    order: ""
};
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sanoop_2340/zcgwua0w/#)